# C# How to separate each number in a String, and store them in an array as Int

Tags: c#, arrays, string, integer, store

let's say I give 1634 as myNum

```
var myNum = Console.ReadLine();
```

and I want t store it in eachNum array as:

```
int[] eachNum = { 1, 6, 3, 4 };
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
var eachNum = myNum.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a costly `int.Parse` here. The `char` representation already has what you need.

```cs
var myNum = 1634;
var eachNum = myNum.ToString().ToCharArray().Select((c) => c - '0').ToArray();
```

If it's already in `String` format, then it's even simpler:

```cs
var myNum = "1634";
var eachNum = myNum.ToCharArray().Select((c) => c - '0').ToArray();
```

If you can't depend on the input being a valid integer, though, then you will need to validate it first:

```cs
var myNum = Console.ReadLine();
int myNumValidated;
if (!int.TryParse(myNum, out myNumValidated)) {
  throw ...;
}
var eachNum = myNum.ToCharArray().Select((c) => c - '0').ToArray();
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't think being lazy should be encouraged here. The OP should at least attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: @beautifulcoder In general, sure, but sometimes the answer is so trivial that it's faster to just type it out than to go out of my way to berate the asker on their laziness. Saves time _and_ they get their answer.